# Why should avoid using Runtime.exec() in java?

Tags: java

```
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   is = p.getInputStream();
   byte[] userbytes = new byte[1024];
   is.read(userbytes);
```

I want to execute a shell command in linux os from java . But pmd reports says don't use java Runtime.exec(). Why? What is the reason ? Is there any alternative for Runtime.exec()?

Comment: What message is pmd showing exactly?

Comment: Problem description: Do not use Runtime.exec() to 
 execute commands

Comment: This is an absurd statement, with absolutely no backing

Comment: What is the reason to avoid executing Runtime.exec() method ? . Is this any injection is possible?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Unless you're stuck on an ancient JVM, [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) makes it much easier to specify a process, set up its environment, spawn it, and handle its file descriptors.

> This class is used to create operating system processes.
>
> Each `ProcessBuilder` instance manages a collection of process attributes. The `start()` method creates a new `Process` instance with those attributes. The `start()` method can be invoked repeatedly from the same instance to create new subprocesses with identical or related attributes.
>
> ...
>
> Starting a new process which uses the default working directory and environment is easy:
>
> ```
>  Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
> ```
>
> Here is an example that starts a process with a modified working directory and environment:
>
> ```
>  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
>  Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
>  env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
>  env.remove("OTHERVAR");
>  env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
>  pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
>  Process p = pb.start();
> ```