# Running command manually with java (using cmd.exe)

Tags: java, cmd, cd

So the following opens a new browser window when I put it in cmd manually:

```
cd C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application&chrome.exe
```

However, when I tried to do this via a java program (see below), the command prompt opens and goes to the correct directory, but no new window opens.  Any ideas of what I need to change?

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start cd C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application&chrome.exe");
```

Comment: have you tried rt.exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");

Comment: I did try, and the machine seems to throw an error at C:/Program.  It doesn't get past that.

Comment: it seems Runtime.exec(String) tokenizes the string, but Runtime.exec(String[]) not, so my last guess would be rt.exec(new String[] {"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start cd \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application&chrome.exe\"");`

Not tested but this shall work, I just put the complete path in double quotes so that because of spaces it's not considered to be the next argument.

If that doesn't work, I suggest trying [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) library, because I always use that.

Here is some sample code from one of my applications :

```
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("cmd.exe");
                    cmdLine.addArgument("/c");
                    cmdLine.addArgument(".\\phantomjs\\nk\\batchbin\\casperjs.bat");
                    cmdLine.addArgument(".\\phantomjs\\nk\\batchbin\\dd.js");
                    cmdLine.addArgument(url);
                    cmdLine.addArgument(">" + rand);
                    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
                    int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
```

Using something like above the complete path to chrome.exe should be added as a new argument, and then the library will take care of escaping.

Comment: I actually just solved this using the Apache Commons library (recommended by another source).  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Try `ProcessBuilder`instead of `Runtime`:

```
String command = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application&chrome.exe";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
Process p = pb.start();
```

See also:

- [Why should avoid using Runtime.exec() in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723346/why-should-avoid-using-runtime-exec-in-java)
- [Difference between ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec)

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  What is the difference between Runtime and ProcessBuilder and, in your opinion, when should I use one over the other?

Comment: Honestly I don't know exactly what the difference is but I use `ProcessBuilder` mainly because you can set environment variables using `pb.environment().put(key,value)`. Also it's more simple to run a command with many parameters separately instead to write them in one large string.

Answer (score 0):

I run a chrome process using:

```
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();            
            builder.command("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "https://your url");            
            Process process = builder.start();
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();        
            assert exitCode == 0;
```