# How to redirect the output to a java stream using java.lang.ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

In the `ProcessBuilder` documentation three methods are provided to redirect the output of a process.

- `ProcessBuilder.Redirect redirectOutput()`
- `ProcessBuilder redirectOutput(File file)`
- `ProcessBuilder redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect destination)`

Question : I want to redirect the process output into a stream instead of a `File`, how this can be achieved.?

Here is the documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to do :**

When you will start you process you will be able to get a `OutputStream` via the `Process` object.

In the documentation of `ProcessBuilder` you can find the method `Process start()`.

With the `Process` object you will be albe to get the `OutputStream` via the method `abstract OutputStream getOutputStream()`.

**Documentation :**

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

**Exemple :**

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = ProcessBuilder("/here/your/command1", "/here/your/command2");
Process process = processBuilder.start();
OutputStream outputSteeam = process.getOutputStream();
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Process instead of ProcessBuilder

Here's an example with Java API Runtime : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

```
// Java runtime
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
// Command
String[] command = {"/bin/bash", "/my/file.sh"};
// Process
Process process = runtime.exec(command);

OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
```

Comment: I disagree. ProcessBuilder is the more high-level alternative, and much less error-prone.

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Comment: This explains it well enough, I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10723391/342852