# Java Spring Boot my app did not display the image (the method exec(String) from the type Runtime is deprecated)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I'm running my app on **CLI** using **Spring Boot with REST API** everything works well just I have one problem after running the app and finishing the process on CLI the image did not display moreover I have this message displayed on my code ***"The method exec(String) from the type Runtime is deprecated"***.

**Full Code Below:**

```
package com.example.demo.cli;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.example.demo.models.Agence;
import com.example.demo.models.CarteCredit;
import com.example.demo.models.Chambre;
import com.example.demo.models.Client;
import com.example.demo.models.HotelPartenaireTarif;
import com.example.demo.models.Lit;
import com.example.demo.models.Propose;
import com.example.demo.models.Reservation;

@Component
public class HotelRestClientCLI extends AbstractMain implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate proxy;
    public static StringToCalendar inputStringToCalendar;
    public static StringToDouble inputStringToDouble;
    public static StringToInt inputStringToInt;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader inputReader;
        String userInput = "";
        try {
            inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            setHotelSearchUrl(inputReader);
            setHotelBookUrl(inputReader);
            do {
                menu();
                userInput = inputReader.readLine();
                processUserInput(inputReader, userInput);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } while (!userInput.equals(QUIT));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean validHotelSearchUrl() {
        return HOTEL_SEARCH_URL.equals("http://localhost:8080/hotelsearch/api");
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean validHotelBookUrl() {
        return HOTEL_BOOK_URL.equals("http://localhost:8080/hotelbook/api");
    }

    @Override
    protected void menu() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(QUIT + ". Quitter.");
        builder.append("\n1. Agence Login.");
        System.out.println(builder);
    }

    private void processUserInput(BufferedReader reader, String userInput) {
        try {
            switch (userInput) {
            default:
                System.err.println("Désolé, mauvaise saisie. Veuillez réessayer.");
                return;
            case QUIT:
                System.out.println("Au revoir ...");
                System.exit(0);
            case "1":
                Agence[] agenceLogin = this.login(reader);
                while (agenceLogin.length == 0) {
                    System.err.println("Identifiant ou mot de passe n'est pas correct, veuillez réessayer !\n");
                    agenceLogin = this.login(reader);
                }
                String agenceLoginId = agenceLogin[0].getIdentifiant();
                System.out.println(agenceLoginId + " login Avec succès!");

                System.out.println("Date arrivée (dd/MM/yyyy) aujourd'hui ou après aujourd'hui: ");
                inputStringToCalendar = new StringToCalendar(reader);
                String dateArrivee = inputStringToCalendar.process();
                Calendar dateArriveeCal = (Calendar) inputStringToCalendar.processToCalendar(dateArrivee);
                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("Date départ (dd/MM/yyyy) après date arrivée: ");
                inputStringToCalendar = new StringToCalendar(reader);
                String dateDepart = inputStringToCalendar.process();
                Calendar dateDepartCal = (Calendar) inputStringToCalendar.processToCalendar(dateDepart);
                while (!dateDepartCal.after(dateArriveeCal)) {
                    System.err.println("Date départ doit être après date arrivée! ");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Date départ (dd/MM/yyyy):");
                    inputStringToCalendar = new StringToCalendar(reader);
                    dateDepart = inputStringToCalendar.process();
                    dateDepartCal = (Calendar) inputStringToCalendar.processToCalendar(dateDepart);
                }
                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("Nombre de personnes à héberger: ");
                inputStringToInt = new StringToInt(reader);
                int nombrePerson = (int) inputStringToInt.process();
                System.out.println();

                String uri = HOTEL_SEARCH_URL + "/agence/propose?" + "agenceLoginId=" + agenceLoginId + "&dateArrivee="
                        + dateArrivee + "&dateDepart=" + dateDepart + "&nombrePerson=" + nombrePerson;
                System.out.println(uri);
                Propose[] allCombinations = proxy.getForObject(uri, Propose[].class);
                if (allCombinations.length == 0) {
                    System.err.println("Désolé, pas d'hôtel correspond. Veuillez réessayer.");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Voici tous les propositions:");
                    int days = this.daysBetween(dateArriveeCal, dateDepartCal);
                    List<String> listChambreId = this.displayAllCombinations(allCombinations, dateArriveeCal,
                            dateDepartCal, agenceLogin, days);
                    String display = "";
                    do {
                        System.out.println("Display image de chambre? y/n ");
                        display = reader.readLine();
                        System.out.println();
                        this.processDisplayInput(reader, display, listChambreId);
                    } while (!display.equals("n"));

                    // IHotelServiceWeb2 reserver
                    System.out.println("Saisir l'identifiant de l'offre pour réserver: ");
                    String identifiantOffre = reader.readLine();
                    System.out.println();
                    Propose offreChoisi = this.checkPropose(allCombinations, identifiantOffre);
                    while (offreChoisi == null) {
                        System.err.println("Désolé, pas d'hôtel correspond. Veuillez réessayer.");
                        System.out.println("Saisir l'identifiant de l'offre pour réserver: ");
                        identifiantOffre = reader.readLine();
                        System.out.println();
                        offreChoisi = this.checkPropose(allCombinations, identifiantOffre);
                    }

                    System.out.println(identifiantOffre + " est choisi.");
                    // Agence login
                    Agence[] agenceLoginRes = this.loginRes(reader);
                    while (agenceLoginRes.length == 0
                            || !agenceLoginRes[0].getIdentifiant().equals(agenceLogin[0].getIdentifiant())
                            || !agenceLoginRes[0].getMdp().equals(agenceLogin[0].getMdp())) {
                        System.err.println("Identifiant ou mot de passe n'est pas correct, veuillez réessayer !\n");
                        agenceLoginRes = this.loginRes(reader);
                    }
                    String agenceId = agenceLoginRes[0].getIdentifiant();
                    System.out.println(agenceId + " login Avec succès!");
                    // Client
                    System.out.println("Nom du client principal: ");
                    String nom = reader.readLine();
                    System.out.println();

                    System.out.println("Prénom de client principal: ");
                    String prenom = reader.readLine();
                    System.out.println();

                    CarteCredit createdCarteCredit = createCarteCredit(reader);

                    uri = HOTEL_BOOK_URL + "/cartecredit";
                    CarteCredit returnedCarteCredit = proxy.postForObject(uri, createdCarteCredit, CarteCredit.class);

                    Client createdClient = new Client(nom, prenom, returnedCarteCredit);
                    uri = HOTEL_BOOK_URL + "/client";
                    Client returnedClient = proxy.postForObject(uri, createdClient, Client.class);

                    HotelPartenaireTarif hotelPartenaireTarif = offreChoisi.getHotelPartenaireTarif();
                    int hotelId = hotelPartenaireTarif.getHotel().getHotelId();
                    List<Chambre> chambreChoisi = offreChoisi.getListChambre();
                    double prixChoisi = agenceLogin[0].prixChoisi(offreChoisi) * days;

                    String reservationId = this.generateResId(agenceLoginRes[0], hotelPartenaireTarif, returnedClient);
                    reservationId = reservationId.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    Reservation createdRes = new Reservation(reservationId, chambreChoisi, dateArriveeCal,
                            dateDepartCal, returnedClient, prixChoisi);
                    try {
                        uri = HOTEL_BOOK_URL + "/reservation";
                        Reservation returnedRes = proxy.postForObject(uri, createdRes, Reservation.class);
                        uri = HOTEL_BOOK_URL + "/addreservationagence/" + agenceId;
                        proxy.put(uri, returnedRes);
                        uri = HOTEL_BOOK_URL + "/addreservationhotel/" + hotelId;
                        proxy.put(uri, returnedRes);
                        System.out.println("Réservé avec succès. Votre numéro de réservation est " + reservationId);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Désolé, il y a un problème avec la réservation. Veuillez réessayer.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) { // format error in cli
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public List<String> displayAllCombinations(Propose[] allCombinations, Calendar dateArrivee, Calendar dateDepart,
            Agence[] agenceLogin, int days) {
        List<String> listChambreId = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Propose propose : allCombinations) {
            System.out.println("Identifiant de l'offre:" + propose.getOffreId() + "\n" + "Nom de l'hôtel"
                    + propose.getHotelPartenaireTarif().getHotel().getNom() + "\n" + "Date de disponibilité: de "
                    + this.calendarToString(dateArrivee) + " à " + this.calendarToString(dateDepart));
            int nombreLits = 0;
            for (Chambre c : propose.getListChambre()) {
                listChambreId.add(c.getChambreId());
                String descLit = "";
                System.out.println("#Chambre Id:" + c.getChambreId());
                for (Lit lit : c.getLitCollection()) {
                    descLit = descLit + lit.toString() + "\n";
                    nombreLits++;
                }
                System.out.println(descLit);
            }
            System.out.println("Nombre de lits totaux proposés:" + nombreLits + "\n" + "Prix total à payer:"
                    + this.doubleToString(agenceLogin[0].prixChoisi(propose) * days)
                    + " (avec pourcentage de commission)" + " (Pour " + days + " nuits)" + "\n"
                    + "--------------------");
        }
        return listChambreId;
    }

    private String calendarToString(Calendar date) {
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dateString = format1.format(date.getTime());
        return dateString;
    }

    private String doubleToString(double prix) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        return df.format(prix);
    }

    private int daysBetween(Calendar dateArrivee, Calendar dateDepart) {
        Date d1 = dateArrivee.getTime();
        Date d2 = dateDepart.getTime();
        return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }

    private Agence[] login(BufferedReader reader) {
        String identifiant = null;
        String mdp = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Veuillez login pour rechercher!");
            System.out.println("Saisir identifiant de l'agence:");

            identifiant = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Saisir mot de passe de l'agence:");
            mdp = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String uri = HOTEL_SEARCH_URL + "/agence/identifiantandmdp?identifiant=" + identifiant + "&mdp=" + mdp;
        Agence[] agenceLogin = proxy.getForObject(uri, Agence[].class);
        return agenceLogin;
    }

    private Agence[] loginRes(BufferedReader reader) {
        String identifiant = null;
        String mdp = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Veuillez login pour réserver!");
            System.out.println(
                    "Saisir identifiant de l'agence (le même identifiant d'agence qui a récupéré les offres):");

            identifiant = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Saisir mot de passe de l'agence:");
            mdp = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String uri = HOTEL_BOOK_URL + "/agence/identifiantandmdp?identifiant=" + identifiant + "&mdp=" + mdp;
        Agence[] agenceLoginRes = proxy.getForObject(uri, Agence[].class);
        return agenceLoginRes;
    }

    private String generateResId(Agence agenceLoginRes, HotelPartenaireTarif hotelPartenaireTarif, Client client) {
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String reservationId = agenceLoginRes.getIdentifiant() + client.getNom() + timestamp.getTime();
        return reservationId;
    }

    private Propose checkPropose(Propose[] allCombinationsList, String identifiantOffre) {
        for (Propose propose : allCombinationsList) {
            if (propose.getOffreId().equals(identifiantOffre)) {
                return propose;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void displayImage(String imageName) throws Exception {
        String uri = HOTEL_SEARCH_URL + "/hotel/image?imageName=" + imageName;
        //      Image image = proxy.getForObject(uri, Image.class);
        //      JFrame imageFrame = new JFrame();
        //        imageFrame.setSize(1024, 683);
        //        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        //        imageFrame.add(imageLabel);
        //        imageFrame.setVisible(true);
        //        imageFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        //      proxy.getForObject(uri, null);

        //        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        //            // Windows
        //            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(uri));
        //        } else {
        //            // Ubuntu
        //            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        //            runtime.exec("/usr/bin/firefox -new-window " + uri);
        //        }
        //      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        //      rt.exec("open " + uri);

        String myOS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("(Votre système d'exploitation est: " + myOS + ")\n");
        try {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) { // Probably Windows
                System.out.println(" -- Aller avec Desktop.browse ...");
                Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                desktop.browse(new URI(uri));
            } else { // Definitely Non-windows
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                if (myOS.contains("mac")) { // Apples
                    System.out.println(" -- Aller sur Apple avec 'ouverte'...");
                    runtime.exec("open " + uri);
                } else if (myOS.contains("nix") || myOS.contains("nux")) { // Linux flavours 
                    System.out.println(" -- Passer sous Linux avec 'xdg-open'...");
                   runtime.exec("xdg-open " + uri);
                } else
                    System.out.println("Je n'ai pas pu lancer de navigateur sur votre système d'exploitation.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("**Trucs à tort: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void processDisplayInput(BufferedReader reader, String display, List<String> listChambreId) {
        try {
            switch (display) {
            default:
                System.err.println("Désolé, mauvaise saisie. Veuillez réessayer.");
                return;
            case "n":
                return;
            case "y":
                System.out.println("Chambre Id ?");
                String chambreId = reader.readLine();
                if (listChambreId.contains(chambreId)) {
                    this.displayImage(chambreId);
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Chambre Id n'est pas correct.");
                }
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private CarteCredit createCarteCredit(BufferedReader reader) {
        // carte credit
        CarteCredit createdCarteCredit = null;
        while (!(createdCarteCredit instanceof CarteCredit)) {
            System.out.println("Numéro de carte crédit (16 chiffres) : ");
            String carteNumero = null;
            try {
                carteNumero = reader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Mois expiré (2 chiffres) : ");
            inputStringToInt = new StringToInt(reader);
            int expireMois = (int) inputStringToInt.process();
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Année expirée (4 chiffres) : ");
            inputStringToInt = new StringToInt(reader);
            int expireAnnee = (int) inputStringToInt.process();
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("CVC code (3 chiffres) : ");
            String cvcCode = null;
            try {
                cvcCode = reader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println();
            createdCarteCredit = new CarteCredit(carteNumero, cvcCode, expireMois, expireAnnee);
        }
        return createdCarteCredit;
    }

//  private XMLGregorianCalendar calendarToXMLGregorianCalendar(Calendar cal) {
//      XMLGregorianCalendar gDateFormatted = null;
//      try {
//          gDateFormatted =
//                  DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(
//                      cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
//                      cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
//                      cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
//                      cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
//                      cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
//                      cal.get(Calendar.SECOND), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
//      } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      return gDateFormatted;
//  }

}
```

I think the problem comes from this code below but I don't know how to fix any suggestions.

```
    public void displayImage(String imageName) throws Exception {
        String uri = HOTEL_SEARCH_URL + "/hotel/image?imageName=" + imageName;
        String myOS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("(Votre système d'exploitation est: " + myOS + ")\n");
        try {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) { // Probably Windows
                System.out.println(" -- Aller avec Desktop.browse ...");
                Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                desktop.browse(new URI(uri));
            } else { // Definitely Non-windows
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                if (myOS.contains("mac")) { // Apples
                    System.out.println(" -- Aller sur Apple avec 'ouverte'...");
                    runtime.exec("open " + uri);
                } else if (myOS.contains("nix") || myOS.contains("nux")) { // Linux flavours 
                    System.out.println(" -- Passer sous Linux avec 'xdg-open'...");
                    runtime.exec("xdg-open " + uri);
                } else
                    System.out.println("Je n'ai pas pu lancer de navigateur sur votre système d'exploitation.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("**Trucs à tort: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The result that I get after finishing the process using CLI (**See image below**):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5bEk.png)

I expect a solution to this problem, thank you

Comment: are you using something like ProcessBuilder ? because that error,  

> "The method exec(String) from the type Runtime is deprecated"

, indicates that.

Comment: No I use `Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();` check my code above

Comment: ok, as it's mentioned, this method is deprecated, instead of that, you can `ProcessBuilder` -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/10723391/2165146

Comment: I know but I'm new in java I don't now how applied this insted of current code any help pls

Comment: by the way, that screenshot you shared, it says "Je n'ai pas pu lancer de navigateur sur votre système d'exploitation." which means "I was unable to launch a browser on your operating system.", so it doesn't belong to any os, depends on your code but is it true ? first check that.

Comment: I checked this but I don't know where the problem is coming from

Comment: after that, you can create ProcessBuilder then start it ->  `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("open" + uri);
 Process p = pb.start();`

Comment: you can debug your code line by line for examine why it's not detecting any os.